# How To Output Vercel Warnings in Yellow Text

Tags: vercel

I am trying to output warnings in Vercel's logs that appear in yellow text and show as a "warning". I am using console.warn(), yet the logs are always output in red and show as errors.

[image: Warning showing as an error]

Vercel is able to output yellow text as you can see below:

[image: Yellow Vercel Warning Text]

Answer (score 1):

console.warn() [is an alias for console.error()](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consolewarndata-args).

In order for a log entry to appear in the expected "Vercel warning format", you must prefix the entry with `Warning:`  followed by your message:

```
console.warn(`WARNING: Returning on 1st attempt request (attempt 0)`);
```

[image: Custom Vercel warning]

This text is case-insensitive. You can see this technique used within the Next.js source: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/src/build/index.ts (search for "Warning: ").